# How to add texts at the bottom of Material-UI GridList Image, in Reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui, codesandbox

I am working on a Mern-stack and I am using Material-UI on my frontend. My GridList is working fine, but I want to have my description text at the bottom of the image instead of in-front of the image.

When I add the text at the bottom it does not display, the image covers it. how can I add a text below/bottom of the image?

[image: Edit funny-cache-xryhl]

```
    import axios from "axios";
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
    import GridList from "@material-ui/core/GridList";
    import GridListTile from "@material-ui/core/GridListTile";
    import GridListTileBar from "@material-ui/core/GridListTileBar";
    import ListSubheader from "@material-ui/core/ListSubheader";
    import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
    import InfoIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Info";
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
    import useMediaQuery from "@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery";
    import { useTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
    import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

    export default function Program() {
      const theme = useTheme();
      const [programData, setProgramData] = useState([]);

      const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
        root: {
         display: "flex",
         flexWrap: "wrap",
         justifyContent: "space-around",
         overflow: "hidden",
         backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
       },
       gridList: {
         width: 1100,
       },
       icon: {
         color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.54)",
       },
     }));
     useEffect(() => {
       axios
       .get("http://localhost:9000/programs")
        .then((response) => {
         setProgramData([...response.data]);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
         console.log(error);
        });
    }, []);

    const matches = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("xs"));
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <GridListTile key="Subheader" style={{ height: "auto" }}></GridListTile>
        <GridList
          cellHeight={390}
          cols={matches ? 1 : 2}
          className={classes.gridList}
          spacing={8}
        >
          {programData.length > 0 &&
            programData.map((tile, index) => {
              return (
                GridListTile
                  key={Math.floor(Math.random() * new Date().getTime())}
                >
                  <img src={tile.programImage} alt={tile.title} />
                  <GridListTileBar titlePosition="top" title={tile.title} />
                  <Typography paragraph>
                    browned, 6 to 8 minutes. Transfer shrimp to a large plate and
                    set aside, leaving chicken and chorizo in the pan. Add
                    pimentón, bay leaves, garlic, tomatoes, onion, salt and
                    pepper, and cook, stirring often until thickened and fragrant,
                    about 10 minutes. Add saffron broth and remaining 4 1/2 cups
                    chicken broth; bring to a boil.
                  </Typography>
                </GridListTile>
              );
            })}
        </GridList>
      </div>
     );
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, the problem is the `img` that has an height set to default at 100%. So it's just necessary to reduce `img` height. In your case you could do something like:

```
<img
   src={tile.programImage}
   alt={tile.title}
   class={classes.image}
/>
```

and in your `useStyles`:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    ...
    image: {
      height: "63%" //63% for example
    }
}));
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-wood-wbpyl?file=/src/App.js) your codesandbox modified.

Comment: Thanks  but that is not what i am looking for.  i want the typography text to show at the bottom of the image, separated from the image, the title is where i wanted it to be @Giovanni

Comment: Oh ok. Let me investigate and I will modify my answer

Comment: @ChukwumaKingsley I updated my answer (and codesandbox) :)

Comment: Thank you @Giovanni, it worked but the image size for every second image got resized and title not properly aligned. I guess this may be very difficult to accomplish

Comment: @ChukwumaKingsley if you set `cellHeight={700}` on `GridList` images will be not resized. The title has the same width of `GridListTile`.

Comment: Thank you @Giovanni, I had to resize the width to make the image the same size and everything work perfectly now. Thank you so much, man.

Comment: No problem @ChukwumaKingsley :)